# Pi access point brilliant (until another pi connects to it!)

Tags: wifi, access-point, dns, hostapd

just joined and have in interesting issue.
I have a Pi3b+ hooked up to my router running hostapd, dnsmasq and openvpn running an airvpn config, it is solid as a rock. It has a static IP on wlan0 192.168.4.1 and serves a local IP range, everything I connect to it works perfectly, with either static IPs or served ones, the firestick streams TV and hardly ever buffers, a success.

However, and a big however  I want another Pi in the network hosting a NAS. I can connect one headless, it gets an IP address and I can SSH into it fine it shows similar speeds to the AP with speedtest-cli.

But as soon as it starts downloading anything, via wget or updates etc, it bugs out the network, it occasionally drops ssh and can kill reconnects without power offs, just having it in the network can make the TV buffer. I was initially trying with a Pi4 and put it down to that possibly being dodgy, but it is exactly the same on a brand new Pi3. I've tried 2 SD cards, multiple reflashes, brand new updated busters and old stretch versions, everything I can think of. I've spoken to AirVPN and nothing is throttled their end.

I'm now at a loss, maybe it is something on the AP with hostapd or dnsmasq configs? I don't know? It is ironic that I can connect multiple different OS's to a Pi-AP without issue but can't get another bloody Pi to work with it ‍♂️

I would be extremely grateful if anyone has any ideas, I've solved loads of stuff but am now sadly beaten.

Comment: "*it is solid as a rock*" - it's not really true, isn't it?

Comment: "it's not really true, isn't it?" - That's a double negative, I think you meant "is",but thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you rename the Pi?  Two boxes with the same name gives networks headaches...

Comment: Yes thank you, AP and client have own hostnames.